# How can I install "locate" command on vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, locate

Vagrant is running on virtualbox of my mac. It seems it is not a usual linux system. I cannot directly use locate command to find files. What command should be used to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vagrant box is real and usual Linux system. If you can't find some commands, try to search and install it

For example, with yum (depend on the linux system)

```
yum search locate
yum -y install mlocate
```

Comment: Also I need to execute "updatedb" as root. Then the locate command works. Thanks so much.